# How to import public key From X.509 SubjectPublicKeyInfo format?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, x509, ecdsa

I serialize the ECDiffieHellmanPublicKey key BLOB to a byte array by **ToByteArray()** method but this method is obsolete.

> ECDiffieHellmanPublicKey.ToByteArray() and the associated constructor
> do not have a consistent and interoperable implementation on all
> platforms. Use ECDiffieHellmanPublicKey.ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo()
> instead.

Microsoft suggest ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo() method instead. when I replace ToByteArray to ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo() method CngKey.Import makes an error:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'The parameter is
> incorrect.'

How can I fix the code:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        var client = new ECDiffieHellmanCng();
        client.KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Hash;
        client.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;

        // var clientPublicKey = client.PublicKey.ToByteArray();
        var clientPublicKey = client.PublicKey.ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo();

        var server = new ECDiffieHellmanCng();
        server.KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Hash;
        server.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;

        // var serverPublicKey = server.PublicKey.ToByteArray();
        var serverPublicKey = server.PublicKey.ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo();

        var enc = Encrypt(client, serverPublicKey, "Hello");
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(enc.Item1));

        var dec = Decrypt(server, clientPublicKey, enc.Item2, enc.Item1);
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dec));
    }

   public static (byte[], byte[]) Encrypt(ECDiffieHellmanCng client, byte[] serverPublicKey, string plainText)
    {
        var cngKey = CngKey.Import(serverPublicKey, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob);
        var sharedSecret = client.DeriveKeyMaterial(cngKey);

        using var aes = Aes.Create();
        aes.Key = sharedSecret;
        aes.GenerateIV();
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        var plainBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
        using var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor();
        var cipherBytes = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);

        return (cipherBytes, aes.IV);
    }

    public static byte[] Decrypt(ECDiffieHellmanCng server, byte[] clientPublicKey, byte[] iv, byte[] cipher)
    {
        var cngKey = CngKey.Import(clientPublicKey, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob);
        var sharedSecret = server.DeriveKeyMaterial(cngKey);

        using var aes = Aes.Create();
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        aes.IV = iv;
        aes.Key = sharedSecret;

        using var decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor();
        var plain = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(cipher, 0, cipher.Length);

        return plain;
    }
```

Comment: See following example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdiffiehellmancng?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is: Instead of `CngKey.Import()` an `ECDiffieHellmanCng()` instance is to be created in the `Encrypt()` and `Decrypt()` methods.
Into this instance the passed public SPKI key is imported with `ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo()`.
To `DeriveKeyMaterial()` the `Key` property of the `ECDiffieHellmanCng()` instance is to be passed.

E.g. for `Encrypt()`:

```cs
public static (byte[], byte[]) Encrypt(ECDiffieHellmanCng client, byte[] serverPublicKey, string plainText)
{
    var server = new ECDiffieHellmanCng();
    server.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(serverPublicKey, out _);
    var sharedSecret = client.DeriveKeyMaterial(server.Key);
    ...
```

Note that `ECDiffieHellmanCng` is only supported on Windows, s. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/cross-platform-cryptography).